# AJAX call over a https service doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm developing a node.js REST service which is being used by a web client with javascript. I was currently offering this services over HTTP. Now I have changed the server to offer them over **HTTPS** and ajax calls have stopped working.

When I set up the server to be over http this client code works (shows the "success!" alert):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Client</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#go").click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", 
                    url: "http://localhost:3010/users", 
                    data: { username: "test", password: "12345" },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("success!");
                   }
                }).error(function (data) {
                    alert("error");
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="go" href="#">go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I change the server to use HTTPS and change the url in the client code:

```js
$.ajax({
   type: "GET", 
   url: "http://localhost:3010/users",
   ...
```

When I use CURL to test the server with the https calls it does work perfectly:

```
curl --insecure "https://localhot:3010/users?username=test&password=12345"
```

I don't understand why the ajax calls fail when using the https services.

Comment: Check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Comment: @Adnan does it depend on the browser? I want the client to be a cordova/phonegap html5 application that will be doing ajax calls to the server.

Comment: @eliocs, #@adnan is right, but there are several "tricks" to overcome this, try searching for "CORS".

Comment: Are your Certs for HTTPS correct? if you go directly to the URL do you get a cert error page this could cause the problem

Comment: @Qpirate the certs have aren't signed by a CA and therefore the browser shows a warning. This could well be the case. In curl I can skip this error with the --insecure option.

Comment: @eliocs, try to accept the certs (in Firefox by ticking "permanently store this exception") and see what happens.

Comment: @Adnan IT WORKS! :), but now I'm lost, is this domain thing an issue?

Comment: You'll have to thank @Qpirate then, he caught the issue. The x-domain thing might become a problem later, so don't worry about it now, when you start having issues read about "Implementing JSONP".

Comment: @eliocs try doing this in your IIS setup http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069 i havent tried it but it should hopefully work.